# How can I confirm payment from user (subscribe button)?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a subscribe button in my website but I don't understand how can I receive notification of the user payment and handle it in php. What information exactly do I receive after the user has payed? And how can I handle that information in a php script to give the user 'premium' conditions in a service?

Comment: Paypal sends you an IPN notification, if you use a form then the returnUrl receives the transaction information that you can check later if it's ok.